# Doctrine Prints Everything in the Object

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a simple code and when I `print_r` it, this one is the output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => App\Entities\EibPerson Object
        (
            [personId:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 10025
            [createdBy:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [createdOn:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2016-12-06 08:33:59.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +03:00
                )

            [modifiedBy:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [modifiedOn:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2016-12-06 08:33:59.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +03:00
                )

            [recordVersion:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [activeFlag:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [firstName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test person name
            [middleName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test middle
            [lastName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test last name
            [displayName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => sorxrob
            [dateOfBirth:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 1992-10-01 03:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +03:00
                )

            [landlineNumber:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 2312321313131
            [mobileNumber:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 876543454
            [emailAddress:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => sorianorobertc@gmail.com
            [heightInches:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 6
            [inseamLengthInches:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 6
            [weightInKgs:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 80.00
            [profilePictureUrl:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [sourceDesc:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => testsourceDesc
            [remarks:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test remarks test
            [memberId:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [externalReferenceId:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [genderEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [address:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [tshirtSizeEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [bloodGroupEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [managingBranch:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [foodPreferenceEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [sourceEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [sourceDetailRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [externalSourceSysEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
        )

    [1] => App\Entities\EibPerson Object
        (
            [personId:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 10026
            [createdBy:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [createdOn:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2016-12-06 08:36:03.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +03:00
                )

            [modifiedBy:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [modifiedOn:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2016-12-06 08:36:03.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +03:00
                )

            [recordVersion:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [activeFlag:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [firstName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test person name
            [middleName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test middle
            [lastName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test last name
            [displayName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => sorxrob
            [dateOfBirth:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 1992-10-01 03:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +03:00
                )

            [landlineNumber:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 2312321313131
            [mobileNumber:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 876543454
            [emailAddress:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => sorianorobertc@gmail.com
            [heightInches:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 6
            [inseamLengthInches:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 6
            [weightInKgs:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 80.00
            [profilePictureUrl:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [sourceDesc:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => testsourceDesc
            [remarks:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test remarks test
            [memberId:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [externalReferenceId:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [genderEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [address:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [tshirtSizeEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [bloodGroupEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [managingBranch:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [foodPreferenceEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [sourceEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [sourceDetailRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [externalSourceSysEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
        )

    [2] => App\Entities\EibPerson Object
        (
            [personId:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 10027
            [createdBy:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [createdOn:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2016-12-06 08:37:25.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +03:00
                )

            [modifiedBy:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [modifiedOn:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2016-12-06 08:37:25.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +03:00
                )

            [recordVersion:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [activeFlag:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 1
            [firstName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test person name
            [middleName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test middle
            [lastName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test last name
            [displayName:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => sorxrob
            [dateOfBirth:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 1992-10-01 03:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 1
                    [timezone] => +03:00
                )

            [landlineNumber:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 2312321313131
            [mobileNumber:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 876543454
            [emailAddress:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => sorianorobertc@gmail.com
            [heightInches:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 6
            [inseamLengthInches:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 6
            [weightInKgs:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 80.00
            [profilePictureUrl:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [sourceDesc:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => testsourceDesc
            [remarks:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => test remarks test
            [memberId:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [externalReferenceId:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [genderEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [address:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [tshirtSizeEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [bloodGroupEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [managingBranch:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [foodPreferenceEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [sourceEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [sourceDetailRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
            [externalSourceSysEnumRid:App\Entities\EibPerson:private] => 
        )
)
```

My code:

```
$person = $this->em->getRepository('App\Entities\EibPerson')->findAll();
print_r($person);
```

What I actually want is to only get this:

[image]

How can I possibly do that? Because I want to json_encode the array but im getting an empty json..

Answer (score 0):

**Debug with max depth**

You could use maxDepth variable of Doctrine Dump.
You can use `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($variable, $depth);` it displays doctrine output without the proxy information.

**More readable output**

If you are using symfony 2.6 or more, I strongly advice you to use `dump()` instead of `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.
Dump shows a well formated and colored output, and you can expand/hide rows.
[image]

**Finally... to json**

To export object(s) to json, I advice you to use serializer and normalizer services, you can find [here in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)